# Prepend not working on Chrome

Tags: jquery, dom

JQuery prepend is not working in Chrome. I have this code:

```
$('#c1').parent().parent().prepend(c1);
```

The unmodified HTML:

```
<span><div><div><img id='c1' /></div></div></span>
```

It doesn't prepend the image to the span. Please guide.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087452/prepend-append-dont-work-opera-safari-chrome. Please check it.

Comment: Are you trying to 'move' the `<img>` element?

Comment: The `<img>` id should be `"c1"` instead of `'c1'`.

Comment: `prepend(c1)` refers to a variable called `c1`. Where is this set?

Comment: @JAiro That thread seems quite a bit more complex...

Comment: c1 equals $('#c1'), that's ok and the apostrophe is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this.

```
    var c1 = $('#c1');
    c1.parent().parent().prepend(c1);
```

Comment: Probably better to set `$('#c1')` to a variable instead of evaluating it twice.

Comment: I used this:
($('#c1').parent().parent().parent()).prepend($('#c1'));

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $('#c1').prependTo($('span'));
```